# Scan ticket in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios5, barcode-scanner

I want to scan the ticket image for retrieving its information automatically as ticket verified. Is there any way to do this by some code. Below is mentioned the link that shows how scanning needs to be done.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAEj9pbZZy8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zbar is the solution to the problem.

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libzbar](https://github.com/H2CO3/libzbar-ios) to scan various types of barcodes and QR code.